# Plane geometry mesh is not receiving shadows in threeJS r86

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am currently learning WebGL and ThreeJS(r86), and I am having difficulty with casting shadows on `THREE.PlaneGeometry` mesh objects. Here is the snippet of code relevant to the lighting in my scene

```
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(0,5,5);
    light.target.position.set(0,0,0);
    light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;       
    light.shadow.camera.far = 1000;      
    light.shadow.camera.left = -500;
    light.shadow.camera.bottom = -500;
    light.shadow.camera.right = 500;
    light.shadow.camera.top = 500;
    light.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(light);
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbw3mpxg/2/) illustrating my problem. I made sure to set both `obj3D.receiveShadow` and `obj3D.castShadow` to true for all the objects in the scene, but the `THREE.PlaneGeometry` mesh is not rendering any shadow effects. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to add enable shadowMap on Renderer. In your example, you assign shadowMap property as 'true' which is wrong.

```
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
```

The plane you are using as floor is rotated to back and it's double sided material. This is not very recommended since shader will will it but calculation can be missing or buggy.

Replace this

```
floor.rotation.x += Math.PI/2;
```

With this to project shadow on real surface.

```
floor.rotation.x -= Math.PI/2;
```

User shadow mapSize as a number power of two

```
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
```

Shadow map's camera bounds are pretty big. Use a smaller.

[Updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/sbw3mpxg/4/)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working as I had intended. I did not realize the back of the plane was buggy with respect to the shader.